# XCTest: How do I prevent Xcode from needlessly recompiling my project if I'm only making changes to my test Target

Tags: xcode, xctest

My Xcode project is very large, in terms of number of source files, and lines of code. 
When I make a change to only the XCTest code, and hit run on a single test, a single test file, or even the whole test suite, Xcode re-compiles my host application first, even if no files have changed in the host application.  It does so every time I make any change to any test file.

This is posing an efficiency challenge with writing tests, because small adjustments in the test code take a long time to re-run and re-validate. (upwards of 3 minutes per run - yes it's that big of a project, and we are already taking many steps to cut down the build time, by inspecting the build logs, etc...)

Using Xcode 10.3 with Swift 4.2

the tests are using:

```
@testable import MyModuleName
```

Is there a way I can prevent Xcode from re-building the whole project, if I've only changed tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

We have some custom scripts under the Project's Build Phases section that actually change some of the compilable assets in the codebase.   We also have a Carthage dependency copy stage.

Commenting out both of these stages from Build phases makes it so that the whole project does not recompile when only changing tests.  These scripts were actually making changes to the compilable code, making XCode force re-compilation.

Moral of the story:  Check your build phases for any steps that could be modifying your source code, including possibly resource files that are part of the target. We will try to do this in a more automated way in the future, without having to comment out these build steps.

Comment: For our build phases that run scripts, we had to explicitly add input/output files or file lists for this very reason.